# AWS equivalent to Azure Building Blocks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

Is there an AWS equivalent to the Azure Building Blocks CLI?

Doing a Google search has not revealed anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with **Azure Building Blocks**, but based on [AWS vs Azure vs Google Cloud: Storage and Compute Comparison](https://n2ws.com/blog/aws-vs-azure-vs-google-cloud), the closest equivalent is [AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html).

> AWS CloudFormation is a service that helps you model and set up your Amazon Web Services resources so that you can spend less time managing those resources and more time focusing on your applications that run in AWS. You **create a template** that describes all the AWS resources that you want (like Amazon EC2 instances or Amazon RDS DB instances), and AWS CloudFormation takes care of provisioning and configuring those resources for you. You don't need to individually create and configure AWS resources and figure out what's dependent on what; AWS CloudFormation handles all of that. The following scenarios demonstrate how AWS CloudFormation can help.

If you want a programmatic equivalent to AWS CloudFormation, [AWS Cloud Development Kit (AWS CDK)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html):

> Use the AWS CDK to define your cloud resources in a familiar programming language. The AWS CDK supports TypeScript, JavaScript, Python, Java, and C#/.Net.